# Entity Framework Projection: Materialize Additional List

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Given the (simplified) object model below, I need to load the `Schedule` object that corresponds to a given `Person`, but only load select `Class`es that the person is taking.

I'm accomplishing that using a projection and it works fine (except for EF Profiler complaining about too many joins).

Now I have a new requirement to also load `Person.FunFacts`.  I hoped the commented-out code `//FunFacts = s.Person.FunFacts,` would accomplish that.  However, it does not.

I can accomplish my goal by accessing `schedule.FunFacts` while the context is still active.  However, that creates an additional round trip to the database.

**Question**: Can I modify my projection to return `schedule.FunFacts` without resorting to lazy loading it via the proxy?

**Object Model** (simplified)

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public List<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
    public List<FunFact> FunFacts { get; set; }
}   

public class FunFact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Materialization Code**

```
var desiredPersonId = 42;
var classIds = new List<int> { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
var schedule = (from sFilter in
                (from s in ctx.Schedules
                 where s.Person.Id == desiredPersonId
                 select new
                 {
                     Schedule = s,
                     Person = s.Person,
                     //FunFacts = s.Person.FunFacts,
                     Class = from c in s.Classes where classIds.Contains(c.Id) select c
                 }
                    ).AsEnumerable()
            select sFilter.Schedule).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `FunFacts` is indeed selected, just not related to the instance of `Schedule`.

Inspired by [an article](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Projection_blows_includes_in_Entity_Framework.aspx), I resolved the issue by making the following changes:

```
var scheduleProjection = 
            (from s in ctx.Schedules
             where s.Person.Id == desiredPersonId
             select new
             {
                 Schedule = s,
                 Person = s.Person,
                 FunFacts = s.Person.FunFacts,
                 Class = from c in s.Classes where classIds.Contains(c.Id) select c
             }
                ).FirstOrDefault();

var schedule = scheduleProjection.Schedule;
schedule.FunFacts = scheduleProjection.FunFacts;
```